# Emailing a piece of Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, dom, jquery-plugins

I want to be able to send a piece of html Dom by email, in a similar fashion I use [jqPrint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) jQuery plugin to print a partial dom. Has anyone seen a project like that?

When a user interacts with my site having a bunch of ExtJs components and RichFaces rendered components, they will want to print/email part of their work in progress as a screen capture for audit purposes. I want to gather up part of the dom, serialize it and send it back to the server, from where I would initiate the email that will look more or less like the screen a user was seeing prior to initiating this action.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Google is doing this in Google+ and a talented developer reverse engineered it and produced http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ . To work in IE you'll need a canvas support library such as http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I looked at that project. It is pretty much on the money. I haven't decided yet if i want to convert the dom into an image and I have not seen it work in IE successfully. However, grabbing parts of a dom, rewriting a few urls (images and styles), is all that's needed. Their [sample](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/screenshots.html) page kind of does that before it calls the actual html2canvas api.